# How would I resize text dynamically to fit into an element for the purpose of preventing a stretch?

Tags: javascript

I want the height of the element the text is in to be 100px no matter what. If there is a paragraph that stretches the element, how would I shrink it until it perfectly fits into the box?

Comment: Something like this? http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

It just so happens I wrote a jQuery plugin to solve this problem.  Here is the link.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-fit-text-to-height/